# How can I tell if my iPhone is accessible for Continuity Camera?

Tags: ventura, continuity

I've recently updated my Intel Retina iMac to Ventura. My iPhone has continuity camera turned on.

Is the only way to see if it's detected by the Mac to try and make a video call and see if the camera is listed? Or can I look in my Mac settings somewhere to see it is detected in advance?

Comment: I use https://handmirror.app, which also helps to check out whether something is shown in the background which you don't want others to see :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run

```
system_profiler SPCameraDataType
```

this should list all available cameras. I can see my iPhone listed there.